# uninstalling system apps from Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: software-uninstall

how to remove livepatch,characters software and language support app from Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend removing the .desktop entry for these apps or removing the apps completly, **it could cause problems which I am not responsable for.**

Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

### Livepatch

You can remove Livepatch from the Apps menu by removing the .desktop entry on /usr/share/applications

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/software-properties-livepatch.desktop
```

### Characters

This is a separate gnome app which you can apt remove

```
sudo apt remove gnome-characters
```

You can remove Characters from the Apps menu by removing the .desktop entry on /usr/share/applications

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Characters.desktop
```

### Ubuntu Software

This is a snap app "Snap store" which you can snap remove

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

You can remove Ubuntu Software from the Apps menu by removing the .desktop entry on /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/

```
sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop
```

### Language support

This is a separate gnome app which you can apt remove

```
sudo apt remove gnome-language-selector
```

You can remove Language support from the Apps menu by removing the .desktop entry on /usr/share/applications

```
/usr/share/applications/gnome-language-selector.desktop
```

Comment: thanks it helps me a lot.

Comment: please tell me how to remove text editor app from Ubuntu. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: to hide `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop` 
to remove from system completly `sudo apt remove gedit`